# Power BI API Authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, azure-active-directory, powerbi

How can I call the Power BI API from my application and understand Microsoft APIs?

I have successfully authorized users via the Azure AD library for JavaScript.  However I have not been able to get a successful response from the API in the console.  I get an unauthorized error, no access control allow origin header is present on the requested resource.

I am used to making API calls using Javascript and Angular, but not with Microsoft APIs and how they must be authorized.  I have tried to read articles but they go over my head.

**The errors are as follows**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> XMLHttpRequest: cannot load https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/dashboards. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://renniesb.github.io is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
>       nope

**Repository with my project code**

https://github.com/Renniesb/sample_dashboard/tree/gh-pages

**Place in repository that shows my Power B.I API call** https://github.com/Renniesb/sample_dashboard/blob/gh-pages/app/services/powerbi.service.js

**Expected behavior** 
List dashboards in the console.

**Test site**

https://Renniesb.github.io/sample_dashboard. To test I authorize with my credentials. How would I let users of this forum test the behavior. How do I enable their credentials?

**List of things I've tried already**

- Created a reverse proxy using the following website: http://shawnsimondeveloper.com/nodeproxyangular/
  Used the JSONP hack to attempt to get around CORS problem.
- Put in the origin of the call in the webconfig file.
- Tested the site both locally and on a webpage on GitHub

Comment: seems like this is exactly what you are trying to do, step by step: https://github.com/sjkp/powerbi-cors-app-ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use both CORS and the HTTP proxy.  Since you are using the ADAL JS library it will automatically append your Power BI token to your outgoing HTTP requests.

You will also need to setup the following:

- Enable implicit grant flow as described in [Step 3](https://github.com/sjkp/powerbi-cors-app-ts#step-3--enable-the-oauth2-implicit-grant-for-your-application)

Also, the dashboards endpoint is still only available in the "beta" version. This was causing the 404's.

- Update your URLs to https://api.powerbi.com/**beta**/myorg/dashboards

To continue to use standard AJAX call with CORS:

- Update your Angular powerbiService service to make HTTP requests directly to the https://api.powerbi.com domain rather than relative urls.